# Installing net framework 4.7.1

Tags: .net, windows

I want to install .NET Framework 4.7.1 on my W10 machine.

After some work around, [stumbled into this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gF1p.png).

I've done some previous research but can't seem to find a way out.

**How can this be fixed?**

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Framework 4.7.1 is supported on the following Windows 10 versions:

- Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (included in-box)
- Windows 10 Creators Update
- Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Take a look at [Supported Client Operating Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-client-operating-systems).

If you have the above version of Windows 10 and you are still facing the problem.

Then I would suggest you uninstall the current version of .Net framework.

And install .Net using the Offline installer.

Download Link : [.NET Offline Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116)

Comment: Thanks @johnny5 for the information. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: I have windows 10 Enterprise edition, but getting the error to install .net 4.7.1. Is there other way around?

Comment: The offline installer didn't work for you? @AsifKhan

Comment: No it didn't. Later I identified in Microsoft documentation, that .NET framework 4.7.x is not supported in Windows 10 Enterprise edition. @Pranshu Dobhal

Answer (score 2):

Please see: [Announcing the .NET Framework 4.7.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/) , the .NET Framework 4.7.1 is supported on the following Windows versions:

- Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (included in-box)
- Windows 10 Creators Update
- Windows 10 Anniversary Update
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 7 SP1

Would help to know your OS details but i can assume the reason is that your OS doesn't meet its system requirement,

To solve this issue, please update your OS at least Win 10 14393 version .

See also: [NET Framework system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements).